# Delphi can not compile the unit create by its "XML Data Binding Wizard"

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd

When I compile the unit, it gives the following message:

> [dcc32 Error] InvoiceV2R31.pas(1952): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IXMLPropertyValueList'

This identifier is frequently used in this unit, but I have no idea about where it is declared. So that is what I want to be helped with.

I'm trying to create a function that uses an XSD stack of files that creates a XML file containing data from a database. So I need this wizard to create the XML document to be used to create the wanted XML file. I don't know any other way to do it. Are there some other components and/or libraries available?

Comment: There is no `IXMLPropertyValueList` type in Delphi's XML RTL. So it is probably something that should be declared in the unit that the Wizard generates. Can you show the actual code that is not compiling?

Comment: I just wonder what part I should show you. The unit is big, more than 50000 lines. But would it be ok if I put the project on some place on internet?

Comment: No. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service. Posts are expected to be self-contained and provide value for future readers. External links can break over time. Please remove any code that is not directly relevant to the question at hand. If the resulting code is still too large, then create a separate [mcve] that demonstrates the same problem, and then show that code.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. I'll do my best and will come back as soon as possible.